# Revert to state before installing a bower component

Tags: angularjs, bower, restore, bower-install

I just installed `angular-pdf` with Bower, and in the installation process, it asked me

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#>=1 <1.3.0 which resolved to 1.2.28 and is required by angular-bootstrap#0.12.0
    2) angular#1.3.15 which resolved to 1.3.15 and is required by angular-cookies#1.3.15, angular-pdf#0.4.0
    3) angular#>= 1.0.8 which resolved to 1.4.1 and is required by ui-router#0.2.13Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

Thinking it would be best to go with the oldest version for most compatibility, I went with 3.

However, this seems to have caused problems. To start with, it seems it reinstalled Angular.

When I run my website now I get

```
TypeError: $browser.addPollFn is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-cookies.js:60)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4443)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4296)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4443)
    at angular.js:4261
    at getService (angular.js:4402)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4434)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (angular.js:4296)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4443)
    at angular.js:4261
```

Is there any way for me to revert everything back to how it was before I ran this Bower installation?

Thanks!

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but are you using any sort of version control?

Comment: @ZackTanner yes I'm using git but I didn't commit for a bit of time beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `bower.json`, you will have portion that has mentioned about the angular resolution you have used

Something like this:

```
"resolutions": {
    "angular": ">= 1.0.8"
}
```

Just remove this portion and in your `devDependencies` set the "angular" version to `1.3.15` and finally in Terminal, run `bower install` and I think angular with version 1.3.15 will take effect.